# buffers overlaying and double counting

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, count

I have layer of water points and a layer of houses. I need to get the number of houses that are within 500 m from a waterpoint. After this I do a spatial join (join one to one) and then I get number of houses that are within 500 m of a waterpoint.

[image]

However many of the buffers are overlaying and I am wandering if the result I get in the attribute table includes all the double counts, and if so, how do I get rid of double counting?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please, ask one question per post. Also, `Join_Count` answer the first question itself

Comment: House sits inside multiple buffers, this spatial join points to houses , one to many will do. Summarise by buffer id to get your answer - frequency. Alternatively use interest, output - points, essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you ask the question:
How many houses are within 500m of a specific water point?
Or
How many houses are within 500m of any water point?

For the first your current result is correct,  you want to keep the water point information.  But if you don't need to know which house is within reach of which water point you can dissolve the point buffer into one large polygon under count the houses inside it.

From your screenshots it seems like you are working with ArcMap. There is an option for the buffer tool to dissolve results. Just use that, or run the dissolve tool after the buffer tool, as you like.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for your answer. I do need to know which houses are within 500m of a specific water point, I need this in order to calculate how many people do to a specific waterpoint. However many houses are within 500 m of more than one waterpoint. I guess to figure out which waterpoint people will go to more likely (shorter distance) is another kind of analysis.

Comment: In that case you can use the near tool which finds the nearest point in one layer for all points in another. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm